Fast and low Memory Requiring Lookup Tree Library
Background
While working on solving the end game of the russian card game Durak I developed a library small_memory_tree to store the simulation results. You can try the game on my website Modern Durak by clicking on puzzle. In the puzzle mode you will play against a computer controlled opponent who uses the results of my solver which are saved using small_memory_tree.
Source Code
I removed all external dependencies besides the std-library.
I mocked the dependency to a tree library.
smallMemoryTree.hxx
#pragma once
/*
Copyright (c) 2024 Waldemar Schneider (w-schneider1987 at web dot de)
Distributed under the Boost Software License, Version 1.0.
(See accompanying file LICENSE.md or copy at http://www.boost.org/LICENSE_1_0.txt)
 */

#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>
#include <complex>
#include <expected>
#include <format>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <numeric>
#include <optional>
#include <ranges>
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>
namespace confu_algorithm
{

// Copied from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/lower_bound
template <std::forward_iterator I, std::sentinel_for<I> S, class T, class Proj = std::identity, std::indirect_strict_weak_order<const T *, std::projected<I, Proj> > Comp = std::ranges::less>
constexpr I
binaryFind (I first, S last, const T &value, Comp comp = {}, Proj proj = {})
{
  first = std::ranges::lower_bound (first, last, value, comp, proj);
  return first != last && !comp (value, std::invoke (proj, *first)) ? first : last;
}
}

namespace small_memory_tree
{

namespace internals
{

template <typename T> concept IsNode = requires (T const a)
{
  {
    a.begin ()
  } -> std::forward_iterator;
  {
    a.end ()
  } -> std::forward_iterator;
  { a.size () };
  { a.data () };
};

// TODO This does not check what kind of iterator it is.
// if we find out how to check if it is a breath first iterator or not we can rename this
template <typename T> concept HasIteratorToNode = requires (T a)
{
  { a.root () };
  { ++a.constant_breadth_first_traversal_begin () };
  { ++a.constant_breadth_first_traversal_end () };
  {
    *a.constant_breadth_first_traversal_begin ()
  } -> IsNode;
  {
    *a.constant_breadth_first_traversal_end ()
  } -> IsNode;
};

}

template <typename ValueType, typename ChildrenOffsetEndType = uint64_t> class SmallMemoryTree
{
public:
  SmallMemoryTree () = default;
  template <internals::HasIteratorToNode TreeAdapter> SmallMemoryTree (TreeAdapter const &treeAdapter)
  {
    auto childrenSum = ChildrenOffsetEndType{};
    std::for_each (treeAdapter.constant_breadth_first_traversal_begin (), treeAdapter.constant_breadth_first_traversal_end (), [&] (auto const &node) mutable {
      values.push_back (node.data ());
      childrenSum += static_cast<ChildrenOffsetEndType> (std::distance (node.begin (), node.end ()));
      childrenOffsetEnds.push_back (childrenSum);
    });
    values.shrink_to_fit ();
    childrenOffsetEnds.shrink_to_fit ();
  }

  SmallMemoryTree (std::vector<ValueType> values_, std::vector<ChildrenOffsetEndType> childrenOffsetEnds_) : values{ std::move (values_) }, childrenOffsetEnds{ std::move (childrenOffsetEnds_) } {}

  // clang-format off
    [[nodiscard]]
  auto operator<=> (const SmallMemoryTree &) const = default;
  // clang-format on

  [[nodiscard]] std::vector<ValueType> const &
  getValues () const
  {
    return values;
  }

  [[nodiscard]] std::vector<ChildrenOffsetEndType> const &
  getChildrenOffsetEnds () const
  {
    return childrenOffsetEnds;
  }

private:
  std::vector<ValueType> values{};
  std::vector<ChildrenOffsetEndType> childrenOffsetEnds{};
};

namespace internals
{
template <typename ValueType, typename ChildrenOffsetEndType = uint64_t>
[[nodiscard]] std::expected<ChildrenOffsetEndType, std::string>
getChildrenCount (SmallMemoryTree<ValueType, ChildrenOffsetEndType> const &smallMemoryTree, uint64_t index)
{
  auto const &childrenOffsetEnds = smallMemoryTree.getChildrenOffsetEnds ();
  if (index >= childrenOffsetEnds.size ()) return std::unexpected (std::format ("Index out of bounds childrenOffsetEnds.size(): '{}' index '{}'", childrenOffsetEnds.size (), index));
  return (index == 0) ? childrenOffsetEnds.at (index) : childrenOffsetEnds.at (index) - childrenOffsetEnds.at (index - 1);
}

template <typename ValueType, typename ChildrenOffsetEndType = uint64_t>
[[nodiscard]] std::expected<std::tuple<uint64_t, uint64_t>, std::string>
childrenBeginAndEndIndex (SmallMemoryTree<ValueType, ChildrenOffsetEndType> const &smallMemoryTree, uint64_t index)
{
  if (auto const &childrenCountExpected = getChildrenCount (smallMemoryTree, index))
    {
      auto const &childrenOffsetEnds = smallMemoryTree.getChildrenOffsetEnds ();
      auto const &childrenCount = static_cast<uint64_t> (childrenCountExpected.value ());
      auto const &childrenOffsetEnd = static_cast<uint64_t> (childrenOffsetEnds.at (index)) + 1 /*end has to be one element after the last element*/;
      auto const &childrenBegin = childrenOffsetEnd - childrenCount;
      return std::tuple<uint64_t, uint64_t>{ childrenBegin, childrenOffsetEnd };
    }
  else
    {
      return std::unexpected (childrenCountExpected.error ());
    }
}
}
template <typename ValueType, typename ChildrenOffsetEndType = uint64_t>
[[nodiscard]] std::expected<std::vector<ValueType>, std::string>
calcChildrenForPath (SmallMemoryTree<ValueType, ChildrenOffsetEndType> const &smallMemoryTree, std::vector<ValueType> const &path, bool sortedNodes = false)
{
  if (not path.empty ())
    {
      auto const &values = smallMemoryTree.getValues ();
      auto nodesToCheckBeginAndEndIndex = std::optional<std::tuple<int64_t, int64_t> >{ std::make_tuple (0, 1) };
      for (auto i = uint64_t{}; i < path.size (); ++i)
        {
          auto const &valueToLookFor = path.at (i);
          if (nodesToCheckBeginAndEndIndex.has_value ())
            {
              auto const &childrenBegin = values.begin () + std::get<0> (nodesToCheckBeginAndEndIndex.value ());
              auto const &childrenEnd = values.begin () + std::get<1> (nodesToCheckBeginAndEndIndex.value ());
              auto const &children = std::span{ childrenBegin, childrenEnd };
              auto nodeItr = children.begin ();
              if (sortedNodes)
                {
                  nodeItr = confu_algorithm::binaryFind (children.begin (), children.end (), valueToLookFor);
                }
              else
                {
                  nodeItr = std::ranges::find (children, valueToLookFor);
                }
              if (nodeItr != children.end ())
                {
                  if (auto const &childrenBeginAndEndIndexExpected = internals::childrenBeginAndEndIndex (smallMemoryTree, static_cast<uint64_t> (std::get<0> (nodesToCheckBeginAndEndIndex.value ()) + std::distance (children.begin (), nodeItr))))
                    {
                      auto const &childrenCount = std::get<1> (childrenBeginAndEndIndexExpected.value ()) - std::get<0> (childrenBeginAndEndIndexExpected.value ());
                      if (childrenCount != 0)
                        {
                          nodesToCheckBeginAndEndIndex = childrenBeginAndEndIndexExpected.value ();
                        }
                      else
                        {
                          nodesToCheckBeginAndEndIndex = std::nullopt;
                        }
                    }
                  else
                    {
                      return std::unexpected (childrenBeginAndEndIndexExpected.error ());
                    }
                }
              else
                {
                  return std::unexpected (std::format ("invalid path. could not find a match for value with index '{}'.", i));
                }
            }
          else
            {
              return std::unexpected (std::format ("Path too long. Last matching index '{}'.", i - 1));
            }
        }
      if (nodesToCheckBeginAndEndIndex.has_value ())
        {
          return std::vector<ValueType> (values.begin () + std::get<0> (nodesToCheckBeginAndEndIndex.value ()), values.begin () + std::get<1> (nodesToCheckBeginAndEndIndex.value ()));
        }
      else
        {
          return std::vector<ValueType>{};
        }
    }
  else
    {
      return std::unexpected ("empty path is not allowed");
    }
}
}

main.cxx
#include "smallMemoryTree.hxx"
#include <iostream>
int
main ()
{
  // creating tree data to mock dependencies
  auto values = std::vector<int>{ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 };
  auto childrenOffsetEnds = std::vector<int>{ 2, 4, 4, 4, 4 };
  auto smallMemoryTree = small_memory_tree::SmallMemoryTree<int, int>{ std::move (values), std::move (childrenOffsetEnds) };
  if (auto rootChildrenExpected = calcChildrenForPath (smallMemoryTree, { 0 }))
    // returns the children of the root node
    {
      auto const &rootChildren = rootChildrenExpected.value ();
      std::cout << std::format ("root has {} children\n", rootChildren.size ());
      std::ranges::for_each (rootChildren, [] (int childValue) { std::cout << std::format ("root child value {}\n", childValue); });
      if (auto child1ChildrenExpected = calcChildrenForPath (smallMemoryTree, { 0, 1 }))
        {
          std::cout << std::format ("child1 has {} children\n", rootChildren.size ());
          auto const &child1Children = child1ChildrenExpected.value ();
          std::ranges::for_each (child1Children, [] (int childValue) { std::cout << std::format ("child1 child value {}\n", childValue); });
        }
      else
        {
          std::cout << child1ChildrenExpected.error () + '\n';
        }
    }
  else
    {
      std::cout << rootChildrenExpected.error () + '\n';
    }
  return 0;
}

Readme
small_memory_tree
Motivation and Goals
small_memory_tree saves data plus the hierarchy information of a tree. It tries to save memory, compared to other libraries that use a vector plus a pointer to the parent as a node(vecPlusPointerToParentNode). Even an empty vector needs 24 Bytes of memory (3 pointers with 8 Bytes on a 64-bit CPU) plus the pointer to the parent node, which is again 8 bytes. This results in 32 bytes of memory (overhead) + memory needed for the value we want to save (payload). If the payload is one byte and the overhead is 32 bytes, this means that out of 33 bytes, only one byte is actually useful.
small_memory_tree saves the payload and the childOffset in a vector. This also means that small_memory_tree can be saved to disk relatively easily.
Limitations
small_memory_tree is not designed to insert or change any data. Please regenerate your tree from small_memory_tree to perform the changes and generate another small_memory_tree. To generate a st_tree or stlplus_ntree from a small_memory_tree, use generateStTree or generateStlplusTree.
How small_memory_tree saves a Tree in Memory
small_memory_tree class member variables
values are the result of saving the data of the tree into a vector, iterating breadth-first.
childrenOffsetEnds is the result of saving the child count of all nodes, iterating breadth-first. And then running partial_sum on that result.
Example of how SmallMemoryTree gets created
Let's say we want to save a tree with 5 nodes whose values fit in an unsigned char, for example, like this:
        0
       / \
      1   2
     /
    3
   /
  4

small_memory_tree will generate a vector called values by iterating breadth first over the tree and saving the node data into values.
In this example:
[0,1,2,3,4]

small_memory_tree will generate a vector called childrenCounts by iterating breadth first over the tree and saving the node childrenCount into childrenCounts. From childrenCounts it will create childrenOffsetEnds using partial_sum on childrenCounts.
In this example:
[2,3,3,4,4]

small_memory_tree template parameter
small_memory_tree is a class templated on ValueType and ChildrenOffsetEndType.
ValueType
ValueType is the Type of data in your nodes.
ChildrenOffsetEndType
It should be an Integer that can hold the size of your tree. If your tree has 200 nodes, you can use uint_8t. If your tree has 400 nodes, you can use uint_16t.
Memory/RAM Consumption
The memory consumption can be calculated with this formula:
automatic_storage_in_byte = size_of(ValueType) + size_of(ChildrenOffsetEndType) * tree.size()
dynamic_storage_in_byte = size_of(values) + size_of(childrenOffsetEnds)
Save more memory
childrenOffsetEnds is the result of childrenCounts partial_sum. So you can reverse partial_sum to get childrenCounts from childrenOffsetEnds. childrenCounts ValueType depends on the childrenCount of your nodes. If no node in your tree has more than 255 children, you can use uint_8t to store the childrenCount information.
small_memory_tree vs stlplus_ntree memory consumption
results are taken from small_memory_tree_memory_measurement.



root with n children uint8_t
messured max heap in Byte stlplus tree
messured max heap in Byte small_memory_tree
memory needed small memory tree compared to stlplus_ntree




2
240
6
2.50%


4
392
10
2.55%


8
712
18
2.53%


16
1,352
34
2.51%


32
2,632
66
2.51%


64
5,192
130
2.50%


128
10,312
258
2.50%


256
20,552
771
3.75%


512
41,032
1,500
3.66%


1,024
81,992
3,000
3.66%


2,048
163,912
6,000
3.66%


4,096
327,752
12,000
3.66%


8,192
655,432
24,000
3.66%


16,384
1,310,792
48,000
3.66%


32,768
2,621,512
96,000
3.66%



small_memory_tree vs st_tree get value by path speed test
Results are taken from  test/benchmarkTest.cxx
find on 10000 children last value is the value we look for. ValueType is uint_64t.



library
g++ libstdc++ find
g++ libstdc++ binary find
clang++ libc++ find
clang++ libc++ binary find




small_memory_tree
2.4134 us
37.0016 ns
2.38974 us
48.5175 ns


st_tree
123.688 us
166.111 ns
135.301 us
202.703 ns



Usage Example with st_tree
As always, for more examples, look in the tests, for example, in test/smallMemoryTree.cxx
create small_memory_tree and retrieve children from the node using a path
#include <iostream>
#include <small_memory_tree/stTree.hxx>
int
main ()
{
  auto stTree = st_tree::tree<int>{};
  stTree.insert (0);
  stTree.root ().insert (1);
  stTree.root ().insert (2);
  stTree.root ()[0].insert (3);
  stTree.root ()[0].insert (4);
  // create a tree using st_tree
  auto smallMemoryTree = small_memory_tree::SmallMemoryTree<int>{ small_memory_tree::StTreeAdapter{ stTree } };
  // create a smallMemoryTree from a stTree using StTreeAdapter
  
  if (auto rootChildrenExpected = calcChildrenForPath (smallMemoryTree, { 0 }))
  // returns the children of the root node
    {
      auto const &rootChildren = rootChildrenExpected.value ();
      std::cout << std::format ("root has {} children\n", rootChildren.size ());
      std::ranges::for_each (rootChildren, [] (int childValue) { std::cout << std::format ("root child value {}\n", childValue); });
      if (auto child1ChildrenExpected = calcChildrenForPath (smallMemoryTree, { 0, 1 }))
        {
          std::cout << std::format ("child1 has {} children\n", rootChildren.size ());
          auto const &child1Children = child1ChildrenExpected.value ();
          std::ranges::for_each (child1Children, [] (int childValue) { std::cout << std::format ("child1 child value {}\n", childValue); });
        }
      else
        {
          std::cout << child1ChildrenExpected.error () + '\n';
        }
    }
  else
    {
      std::cout << rootChildrenExpected.error () + '\n';
    }
  return 0;
}

Save small_memory_tree to the database and restore small_memory_tree
#include <small_memory_tree/stTree.hxx>
int
main ()
{
  // create a tree using st_tree
  auto stTree = st_tree::tree<uint8_t>{};
  stTree.insert (0);
  stTree.root ().insert (1);
  stTree.root ().insert (2);
  stTree.root ()[0].insert (3);
  stTree.root ()[0].insert (4);
  // create a smallMemoryTree from a stTree using StTreeAdapter
  auto smallMemoryTree = small_memory_tree::SmallMemoryTree<uint8_t>{ small_memory_tree::StTreeAdapter{ stTree } };
  // store values and childrenOffsetEnds in your database
  auto const &values = smallMemoryTree.getValues ();
  auto const &childrenOffsetEnds = smallMemoryTree.getChildrenOffsetEnds ();
  //  later in your code retrieve values and childrenOffsetEnds from your database
  auto const &valuesFromDatabase = std::vector<uint8_t>{ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 };
  auto const &childrenOffsetEndsFromDatabase = std::vector<uint8_t>{ 2, 4, 4, 4, 4 };
  //  create smallMemoryTree with data from database
  auto smallMemoryTreeFromDatabase = small_memory_tree::SmallMemoryTree<uint8_t, uint8_t>{ valuesFromDatabase, childrenOffsetEndsFromDatabase };
  return 0;
}

Build
Requirements

Compiler with c++23 support (std::expected)

CMake

The following c++ libraries are required:

boost/1.84.0
confu_algorithm/1.0.1


The following c++ libraries are optional:

stlplus/3.16.0  Pass WITH_STLPLUS_TREE to cmake
st_tree/1.2.2  Pass WITH_ST_TREE to cmake
catch2/2.13.7 Pass WITH_TESTS to cmake



The recommended way to build small_memory_tree is using the conan package manager
As someone who wants to contribute to small memory tree development

Check out small memory tree
Use conan remote to add ''
conan remote login modern_durak read -p 'B2"bi%y@SQhqP~X'
Run conan install
Configure CMake with:

BUILD_TESTS true
WITH_ST_TREE true
WITH_STLPLUS_TREE true
CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE conan_toolchain.cmake


Build the project using CMake
Run the tests target with build/test/_test

As  someone who wants to use small memory tree as a library

Use conan remote to add 'http://modern-durak.com:8081/artifactory/api/conan/conan-local' as modern_durak
conan remote login modern_durak read -p 'B2"bi%y@SQhqP~X'
Add small_memory_tree/SomeVersion as a requirement to your conanfile.py
If you want to use st_tree::tree or stlplus::ntree set the option with_st_tree or with_stlplus_tree to true
Add small_memory_tree to your CMake

Use another tree library with small_memory_tree
small memory tree currently supports st_tree::tree and stlplus::ntree. small_memory_tree can be used with other tree libraries by inheriting from BaseNodeAdapter and BaseNodeAdapter from smallMemoryTreeAdapter.hxx. See stTree.hxx for an example implementation


The API is confusing
I get that this is class is meant to store trees in a compact, serializable form, and that it's not meant to be altered after being created. However, class SmallMemoryTree itself has no way to iterate over nodes or search for nodes. You have some out-of-class functions, but they don't allow iterating in a normal way. Just to figure out the value of the root node, you have to call getValues().
Consider that you have a constructor that takes any type that conforms to the concept HasIteratorToNode. I would then expect that your tree class itself would also conform to that concept, and provide root(), constant_breadth_first_traversal_begin() and constant_breadth_first_traversal_end() member functions.
Don't use std::string as an error code
Using std::expected<> to return a value or a possible error is great! However, using std::string for the unexpected case is bad. While a string might be helpful for the user (if it is printed somewhere they read it), it's hard for a caller in the program itself to do anything with a string. You certainly don't want to start parsing strings. It's better to create your own error class that holds an error code and optionally a string as well. Even better is to create a custom category for std::error_code and use that.
Use your template parameter types consistently
The function childrenBeginAndEndIndex() is a template with the template parameter ChildrenOffsetEndType. I would expect the return value of this function to reutrn a pair of ChildrenOffsetEndTypes, but it's been hardcoded to use std::uint64_t instead. The parameter index should probably also be of ChildrenOffsetEndType.
You can store trees even more compactly
While your trees are quite a bit smaller than one where each node's children are stored in a separate std::vector, you are still wasting a full integer per node. You can do much better by storing only two bits per node: one bit to indicate whether it has children, and one bit to indicate whether it has a right sibling. The drawback is that this makes traversing the tree even harder.
